# Using parsley js to validate form

Tags: angularjs, parsley.js

I must be overthinking this or something. I've read all over the parsley form validation site and, as far as I can tell, it simply passively responds to attributes set up in the DOM. It needs another component to actually change those attributes before one has a working form. Since I'm using Angular, presumably, this is parsleyJS for Angular.

I'm trying to have my SAVE button disabled until the form is valid. I would think that this would be Form Validation 102.

Their super-simple demo doesn't even have a save button and it doesn't bother showing any CSS, so frankly I'm not sure exactly what it is supposed to be demonstrating. If I've got to write the CSS and the form validation, I'm not sure what parsley is actually doing for me.
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

What I'd really like is to find some plunkers showing parsley actually working end-to-end, but they don't seem to believe in plunkers. I don't seem to find an example where the form is actually validating and setting some value to true or false that I can capture to use in my controller.

(This sounds negative, but I'm not really down on parsley, I'm just stumped and time is running out.)

Comment: I could write the necessary code myself to wire this up, but I want to avoid too much of that if possible. This is part of a large project, and I'm setting a precedent here. I'm big on maintainability of code, so I would really prefer to do it the "correct" way. By correct, I mean: if they have supplied a solution that is elegant and takes full advantage of the strengths of the plug-in, then I really want to use that. Future developers will appreciate use of best practices.

Comment: Running into the same problem with data-parsley-equalto. Does nothing. No errors, non examples, no way to know how to implement it correctly.

Comment: You should use events.
BTW, the simple example has a "save button" (it shows as "Validate")